# Grub2: Set font dynamically based on video resolution?

Tags: grub2

I want to modify my grub.cfg to select the font dynamically based on the screen resolution.  I have a 4K display on my laptop, but often boot with a 1080 external monitor, and the font that works on the 4K display is huge if using the external screen.  I do not want to force a lower resolution.  I can mostly determine the current video mode based on the output of the 'videoinfo' command, but I don't see how to get the output of that command into a variable so that I can parse it with the 'regexp' command.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the resolution you want grub to support by editing the following line in `/etc/grub/default` :

`GRUB_GFXMODE=width1xheight1;width2xheight2;width3xheight3`

More infos on [grub's manual (gfxmode)](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/gfxmode.html)

Comment: Right.  I don't want to run in a different graphics mode.  I want the default highest supported resolution.  Then I want grub to dynamically recognize which resolution it's running at, based on the monitor connected at boot time, and select from the installed fonts.  From the command line, I can use the videoinfo command to see what the resolution is, but I don't see how to capture the output of that command as part of the configuration script.

Comment: then why not setting `GRUB_GFXMODE=auto` ? Also, the config script is generated only on `update-grub` so if you put `videoinfo`'s output in `/etc/default/grub` then update grub and change screen, it won't match the resolution.

Comment: I want to put something directly into the grub.cfg.  My point is to modify the output of update-grub or even  bypass it entirely if necessary.  As it is, I am using GRUB_GFXMODE=auto, but that generates different resolutions on different monitors, and I can't figure out how to modify grub.cfg to use a different font depending on what that "auto" translated into for the screen in question.  In other words, the grub.cfg file is static, but the boot conditions are dynamic, so I need to add some dynamic behavior into grub.cfg.